# Why doesn't PuTTY show the vi mode I'm in?

Tags: linux, vim, putty

I'd like vi to show `-- INSERT MODE --`  whenever I tap <kbd>I</kbd> to enter insert mode, but it doesn't show such a message when I use it with PuTTY.

Why does it happen? And how do I make Vim display the mode I'm in? This is very important for me to get it right the first time.

Comment: I don't believe this has anything to do with Putty. It's just a vi/vim setting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the following line in your `.vimrc` file. It will show the current mode on the last line.

```
set showmode
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe putting `set showcmd` in your `.vimrc` should do the trick. (Or just enter `:set showcmd` from inside vim)

Answer (score 0):

Finally,I solved this problem by reinstall vim!
I think my Ubuntu OS caused this problem,as I'm using Chinese localization  Ubuntu,there are some bugs with it.
I will try native Ubuntu later,thanks all !